# step-functions-local: Can't start state machine within state machine

Tags: serverless-framework, state-machine, aws-step-functions, state-machine-workflow, serverless-framework-step-functions

I've got [step-functions-local](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/sfn-local.html) and [serverless-offline](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serverless-offline) configured to test a state machine (let's call it #1) that triggers another state machine (#2) defined within the project.

Both show as created when I fire up the local server with `sls offline start --stage dev`:

```
[Serverless Step Functions Local] 2022-07-29 11:03:59.867: [200] CreateStateMachine <=
{"sdkResponseMetadata":null,"sdkHttpMetadata":null,"stateMachineArn":"arn:aws:states:us-east-1:123:stateMachine:Foo",
"creationDate":1659117839863}

[Serverless Step Functions Local] 2022-07-29 11:03:59.883: [200] CreateStateMachine <=
{"sdkResponseMetadata":null,"sdkHttpMetadata":null,"stateMachineArn":
"arn:aws:states:us-east-1:123:stateMachine:Bar","creationDate":1659117839882}
```

I then test #1 with the following command:

```
aws stepfunctions --endpoint http://localhost:8083 start-execution --state-machine \
arn:aws:states:us-east-1:123:stateMachine:Foo --name local-test-$RANDOM --input <JSON string payload>
```

#1 executes several steps successfully, including read/write S3 operations, until it reaches the step to trigger #2; at that point, it fails with an exception that reads in part:

```
"Error":"StepFunctions- StateMachineDoesNotExistException",
"Cause":"State Machine Does Not Exist: 'arn:aws:states:us-east-1:123:stateMachine:Bar' 
(Service: AWSStepFunctions; Status Code: 400; Error Code: StateMachineDoesNotExist
```

Here's how the step to start state machine #1 is defined in the #1 .yml file:

```
 BarStateMachine:
      Type: Task
      Resource: "arn:aws:states:::states:startExecution.sync:2"
      Parameters:
        StateMachineArn:
          arn:aws:states:us-east-1:123:stateMachine:Bar
```

I can get #1 to work if, instead of pointing to the arn for the locally-created #2, I point it to the arn of the deployed version. However, this deployed version is of course a remote resource, which sort of defeats the purpose of local testing. Any ideas on how to get the local version of #2 executed properly?

Comment: Not 100% certain, but fairly sure that the commands you have listed created each State Machine in their own local environments that cannot talk to each other.  You would have to deploy them both through a single command so they are in the same local "space"

Answer (score 0):

Try something like `export STEP_FUNCTIONS_ENDPOINT=http://localhost:8083 && serverless offline start` - that should cause step function local to use itself for the step function service integration.